# How to convert date column into different format?

Tags: oracle

I have a data column(VARCHAR2) like shown below,

```
Apr 25 2014
Oct 28 2010
Dec 17 2004
Jan 20 2006
```

I need this data in a different format like,

```
25-APR-14
28-OCT-10
17-DEC-04
20-JAN-06
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What is the datatype of this column?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F

Comment: Its varchar2 @APC

Comment: Convert the column to `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) data type. Then you can **display** it in any format you (or better the end user) like to see.

Comment: I'm getting this error ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Please show us your SQL command.

Comment: SELECT TO_DATE(CREATION_DATE, 'MON DD YYYY') FROM ACCOUNTS;

Comment: Try `TO_DATE(CREATION_DATE, 'MON DD YYYY', 'nls_date_language = american')`

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Not a valid month.

Comment: Sorry, it is working there are some hard coded null data present in column. Fixed the issues...thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to cast your string into a date: That's easier enough:

```
select to_date(your_col, 'Mon DD YYYY') your_col_dt
from your_table
```

The column will render in the default NLS date format, which from your question I guess is `DD-MON-YY` so no further tweaking should be necessary.

> I'm getting the same error. Not a valid month

Note that because your column is defined as a varchar2 it can contain all kinds of rubbish, from "dates" in different formats to things which are simply not valid dates under any mask. If this is your situation you will need a function to handle the conversion.